# microsoft face api error Resource not found(404)

Tags: c#, http-status-code-404, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I am running the microsoft face api and getting the exception "Resource not found(404)".
tried both (separately) nuget packages:

[image]

[image]

I am using the following code :
[image]

and the azure face configuration is the following:
[image]

Why I'm getting this error?
And another little question, is the 'Location' important or just a matter of response time?

Answer (score 1):

If you check the [source repo](https://github.com/torutek/Cognitive-Face-Windows) of [Torutek.Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Torutek.Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face/) you will find that it is actually a fork of [Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face.DotNetStandard](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face.DotNetStandard/) which is basically the [original repo](https://github.com/microsoft/Cognitive-Face-Windows), thus, they are both the same, but obviously the original repo is more up to date since it is the original!

In the original repo, you can find that it states the following:

> This SDK has been deprecated and been replaced by
>   [Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.Face](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/cognitiveservices/Vision.Face) which is a part of
>   Azure SDK.

So the solution to your problem is to basically use the new and working NuGet package since the 2 you're currently using are deprecated:

- [Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.Face](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.Face/2.5.0-preview.1)

You can also find a step by step guide on how to use it in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/quickstarts/csharp-sdk)